# Apple push notification services in java, linux development machine

Tags: java, ios, linux, ssl, apple-push-notifications

I'm developing a mobile application with a mac, but it connects to a test server I'm running on linux and I'd like to enable APN on this server with a developer certificate, the question is, is it possible to install this certificate on my test server or I'll have to setup the test server on my linux machine?

To make this a little bit clearer:

My development machine: A Mac.
The test server: A linux machine running liferay 6.0.6

I want to install the development certificate on the test server so I can test push notifications.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: For your test server development, what language are you using?

Comment: Java, in fact it is a liferay application in which I added Jersey

Comment: [Not clear from your question]  Is the 'test server' is on the linux machine already and you just want to add the certificate for APN notifications or is the server somewhere else?

Comment: Just edited to answer your question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to answer my own question because it might help someone, first of all, I had a terrible confusion between the certificates I needed to generate and how to get the device token among other things.

These are the steps I went through to make this work:

- Created an application ID.
- Created a Certificate Signing Request using "Keychain access" and got the development certificate for push notifications which I installed using again Keychain access.
- Exported the certificate as a .p12 file.
- Used the notnoop java library (which is on the central maven repository) to send push notifications.

Here is a sample snippet that shows where the certificate fits in:

```
ApnsService service =
    APNS.newService()
    .withCert("/path/to/certificate.p12", "MyCertPassword")
    .withSandboxDestination()
    .build();
```

The second argument of the method is the password for the p12 file that keychain access makes you to set.

Finally to glue things, I used the `[UIApplication sharedApplication]` instance to register to receive push notifications and by implementing a method on the AppDelegate I get the token I needed which was in NSData format, so you need to converted into a hex string (there is sample code for that in many sites and questions on this site).

And that's it, that's the process.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about 'liferay' but this his how I setup a APN connection (on a Rails server) using the certificate.  Note that you need to convert the certificate to a .pem file (using 'openssl pkcs12 -in myfile.p12 -out myfile.pem'):

```
  @@apn_cert       = nil
  APN_SSL_KEY_FILE = 'lib/SSLCert_Private_Key.pem'
  APN_SSL_HOST     = 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com'
  #  APN_SSL_HOST     = 'gateway.push.apple.com'
  APN_SSL_PORT     = 2195
  APN_SSL_PASSWORD = '<password>'

  def configure_apn_cert
    puts "APN Service: Configuring APN cert"
    @@apn_cert         = File.read(File.join(RAILS_ROOT, APN_SSL_KEY_FILE))
    @@apn_context      = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
    @@apn_context.key  = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(@@apn_cert, APN_SSL_PASSWORD)
    @@apn_context.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(@@apn_cert)
  end

  def create_and_configure_apn_server
    configure_apn_cert if not @@apn_cert
    puts "APN Service: Configuring APN SOCKET and SSL connection"
    @apn_socket       = TCPSocket.new(APN_SSL_HOST, APN_SSL_PORT)
    @apn_ssl          = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new(@apn_socket, @@apn_context)
    @apn_ssl.sync     = true
    @apn_ssl.connect
  end

  def close_apn_server
    @apn_ssl.close
    @apn_socket.close
  end

  def package_build_for_apn( token, content )
    "\0\0 #{token}\0#{content.length.chr}#{content}"
  end

  def package_send_to_apn( package )
    puts "APN Service: Sending #{package}"
    bytes_written = @apn_ssl.write( package )

    if bytes_written != package.length then
      puts "APN Service: SSL write failed"
      package_to_apn_show_write( bytes_written, package)
    end
  end

  def apn_deliver_payload( token, payload )
    # Convert the device string back into a byte string
    tokenBinary = Base64.decode64( token )

    # Transform the payload into an APN byte string
    apn_content      = payload.to_hash.to_json
    apn_content_len  = apn_content.length

    # Build the apn_package per APN specification
    apn_package = "\0\0 #{tokenBinary}\0#{apn_content_len.chr}#{apn_content}"

    # Actually send it.
    package_send_to_apn( apn_package )
  end

  def package_to_apn_show_write( bytes, package)
    puts "Wrote: #{bytes_written}/ Tried: #{package.length}"
    puts "Package: '#{package}'"
  end

  def package_to_apn_debug( token, content, package )
    puts "Token(#{token.length}): #{token}"
    puts "Content(#{content.length}): #{content}"
    puts "Package(#{package.length}): #{package}"
  end
```

Comment: I'll try to translate it into java and I tell you how it went